# How can we convert simulink block diagram(simulink model) into MATLAB code?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to automatically convert my Simulink Block diagram into MATLAB code, but I am unable to find any relevant option. Although C code and HDL code options are available, no option seems to be available for generating MATLAB code. 
How to automatically/directly convert a Simulink Block diagram into MATLAB code?

Answer (score 1):

While you can write a Simulink block in MATLAB code, not all Simulink blocks are written in MATLAB. Converting a Simulink block to C code may be the only way to see the logic, which you can then rewrite in MATLAB if required.

As for trying to look under the hood, unfortunately many of Simulink's block diagrams are proprietary code. [According to this MATLAB forum post](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/33679-the-source-code-of-the-library-componenta), MathWorks' standard response to accessing Simulink source code is getting a job with them.

Comment: This seems to be the only sensible answer. Proprietary functions, also those in MATLAB itself, aren't necessarily written in MATLAB and are thus not easy to convert to MATLAB code directly.